# Apache mod_rewrite for sub domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, dns, subdomain

I'm looking to do some simple mod_rewrite but im kinda new to this. I am looking to be able to visit http://login.markrdbaker.com and that will route to http://markrdbaker.com/stuff/login.php

Basically I would like to achieve the following:

there is a file

```
domain.com/stuff/login.php
```

i wish to be able to go

```
login.domain.com
```

rather than

```
domain.com/stuff/login.php
```

any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would defile a virtual host that handles both the domain and the subdomain.
The you can use a RewriteCond to check if a rewrite should be applied.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
ServerAlias login.domain.com
...
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}   ^login.domain.com
RewriteRule ^/.*$ http://domain.com/stuff/login.php [R=302,L]
</VirtualHost>
```